# Store a set in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am using Python and I would like to have a list of IDs stored in disk preserving some of the functionalities of a set (that is, efficiently checking if an ID is contained). To this end, I think using SQLite library is a wise decision (at least that is my impression after googling and stacking a bit). However, I am a beginner in SQL world and could not find any post explaining what I am looking for.

How can I store IDs (strings) in SQLite and later check if a specific ID appears or not in the database?

```
import sqlite3
id1 = 'abc'
id2 = 'def' 

# Initialization of the database
define_database() 
# Update the database by inserting a new ID
insert_in_database(id1) 
insert_in_database(id2)
# Check if the specified ID is contained in the database (returns a Boolean)
check_if_exists_in_database(id1)
```

PS: I am aware of the sqlite3 library.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a one-column table. Each ID is inserted on a separate row. If the column is indexed, lookups will be very fast with e.g. `select 1 from table where id = 'abc'`. Each of these steps you should be able to find in any SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a table with a single column. This column must be indexed (explicitly, or by making it the primary key) for lookups over large data to be efficient:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('...filename...')

def define_database():
    db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyStuff(id PRIMARY KEY)')
```

(Use a [WITHOUT ROWID table](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) if your Python version is recent enough to have a modern version of the SQLite library.)

Inserting is done with standard SQL:

```
def insert_in_database(value):
    db.execute('INSERT INTO MyStuff(id) VALUES(?)', [value])
```

To check whether a value exists, just try to read its row:

```
def check_if_exists_in_database(value):
    for row in db.execute('SELECT 1 FROM MyStuff WHERE id = ?', [value])
        return True
    else:
        return False
```